# How to import zipped files in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have more than 50 .sql files and I want to import it in my phpmyadmin interface using the import function inside my database all at once. how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell there isn't a way from within phpMyAdmin to upload multiple files at once (if you compress multiple files in to a .zip file, it only processes the first one).

I'd suggest concatenating the files locally and importing the resulting large file. You can do that rather trivially from the Mac and *nix command line with something like

```
cat *.sql > bigfile.sql
```

or by being more specific:

```
cat first.sql 1.sql 5.sql last.sql last-one-this-time-i-mean-it.sql > bigfile.sql
```

I believe the Windows way is nearly identical. This is from memory, so no promises:

```
type file1.sql file2.sql > bigfile.sql
```

Then you can upload bigfile.sql (provided it isn't too big for the PHP resource limits; if it is just do them in chunks or use the UploadDir feature).

Good luck